# Selecting less than / higher than in sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I would like to insert data to a new table where the AmountSpent in tblFinance for CategoryID'?' is < the budget in tblCategory which is linked to the ID

e.g.
If AmountSpent = 1000, CategoryID = 1 CategoryBudget = 900, insert the amountspent into tblExpRptOver and if it's less than the budget, insert to tblExpRptUnder.
I've tried what I thought should work but it gives me this error:

```
 line 613, in test
    'CategoryID = ? AND AmountSpent < ? ', (category_input, budget_input, ))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

The code I'm trying to execute is:

```
view_avg = input("Would you like to view the averages for under/over expenses for a specific category? Y/N \n")
if view_avg == "Y":
    category_input = input("Please input the CategoryID for the category you'd like to view the averages for:"
                           "\n")
    budget_input = ('SELECT CategoryBudget FROM tblCategory WHERE CategoryID = ?', (category_input, ))
    c.execute('INSERT INTO tblExpOver SELECT CategoryID, AmountSpent FROM tblExpRptMonth WHERE '
              'CategoryID = ? AND AmountSpent < ? ', (category_input, budget_input, ))
    c.execute('INSERT INTO tblExpUnder SELECT CategoryID, AmountSpent FROM tblExpRptMonth WHERE '
              'CategoryID = ? AND AmountSpent > ? ', (category_input, budget_input,))
    df_avg_over = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM tblExpOver", conn)
    df_avg_under = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM tblExpUnder", conn)
    with PdfPages('GraphByMonth.pdf') as pdf:

        firstPage = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69, 8.27))
        firstPage.clf()
        txt = 'Average Expense on Over Expenses for Category ', category_input, ':',\
              df_avg_over["AmountSpent"].mean()
        txt1 = 'Average Expense on Under Expenses for Category ', category_input, ':', \
               df_avg_under["AmountSpent"].mean()

        firstPage.text(0.5, 0.5, txt, txt1, transform=firstPage.transFigure, size=24, ha="center")
        pdf.savefig()
        plt.close()

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.69, 8.27))
        df2.plot(kind='bar')
        plt.title('Expense Graph by Month')
        txt = 'Month Expense Graph'
        plt.text(0.05, 0.95, txt, transform=fig.transFigure, size=24)
        plt.xlabel("Expense Number")
        plt.ylabel("Amount Spent")
        pdf.savefig()
        plt.close()
    menu()
```

Any help is appreciated!
EDIT: CategoryBudget is stored in a different table for category information - tblCategory.

Comment: `budget_input` is a tuple. You never execute that query.

Comment: Oh so just add c.execute?

Comment: You also would need to fetch the result and assign that to `budget_input`. But see my answer for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never executing the `budget_input` query. You can't use a placeholder for a `SELECT` query.

Instead of doing a separate query, you should join the `tblCategory` table in the `INSERT ... SELECT` query.

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO tblExpOver 
            SELECT r.CategoryID, r.AmountSpent 
            FROM tblExpRptMonth AS r
            JOIN tblCategory AS c ON r.CategoryId = c.CategoryId AND r.AmountSpent < c.CategoryBudget
            WHERE r.CategoryID = ?''', (category_input,))
c.execute('''INSERT INTO tblExpUnder 
            SELECT r.CategoryID, r.AmountSpent 
            FROM tblExpRptMonth AS r
            JOIN tblCategory AS c ON r.CategoryId = c.CategoryId AND r.AmountSpent > c.CategoryBudget
            WHERE r.CategoryID = ?''', (category_input,))
```

Note that you never insert anything for rows that are exactly equal to the budgeted amount. Unless that's intentional, you should change either `<` or `>` to `<=` or `>=`, depending on which category you want them to be in.

Also, it seems like you may have `<` and `>` backwards, if the `Over` and `Under` table names mean that the spending is more and less than the budgeted amount.

Comment: Oh ok, would this code work for what I want it to do though?? Because CategoryBudget is stored in a seperate table from AmountSpent

Comment: Of course, `r.AmountSpent` means to get `AmountSpent` from `tblExpRptMonth`, while `b.CategoryBudget` comes from `tblCategory`

Comment: I'm getting this error now and don't know what it means? line 616, in test
    WHERE r.CategoryID = ?''', (category_input,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: ambiguous column name: CategoryID

Comment: I forgot to put the `r.` alias in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Would I just do another JOIN statement? Sorry to keep asking, I'm very new to this... Not too sure how to do this bit!

Comment: Another join statement for what?

Comment: r. alias, where would it go in the select list?

Comment: I edited the answer with the fix when I wrote that comment. `SELECT r.CategoryID, r.AmountSpent`

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you so much for your help and patience!